# Does Harry Potter have phobophobia?

Tags: harry-potter

I recently came across this fear -

> **Phobophobia** is a fear of being afraid. Some people might be terrified of the physical symptoms that come with fear, such as rapid breathing or dizziness. Others are scared of developing another phobic disorder.

And I got really confused. Basically, Harry fears fear, as Lupin tells Harry in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*.

> “I didn’t think of Voldemort,” said Harry honestly. “I — I remembered those dementors.”
>
> “I  see,”  said  Lupin thoughtfully. “Well,  well  ...  I’m  impressed.” He smiled slightly at the look of surprise on Harry’s face. “That suggests that what you fear most of all is — fear. Very wise, Harry.”
>
> Harry didn’t know what to say to that, so he drank some more tea.

The definition of phobophobia is "fear of ***fear of being afraid***" but Harry fears fear itself . . . and phobophobia is the closest word for Harry's fear (other than dementorphobia, which is great ofc) . . . so does Harry have phobophobia?

Comment: I apologize for how confusing this question may sound. It took me a while to put my confusion into words . . . this is really the best explanation for it.

Comment: I thought Phobophobia was the fear of Vietnamese noodle soup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While fear might be the thing Harry is afraid of *most* (and I'm not convinced that's true or even really what Lupin was trying to say), there's no indication that it would rise to the level of a clinical phobia and ample evidence throughout the books that would argue against it. Harry is consistently presented as particularly brave in the face of scary situations.

Your question mentions that those who suffer for phobophobia "might be terrified of the physical symptoms that come with fear, such as rapid breathing or dizziness" or "are scared of developing another phobic disorder" and Harry displays neither of those characteristics.

Comment: I fail to see the logic in concluding that acting bravely is inconsistent with fear of being afraid.  I can imagine a character who is never afraid being frightened of feeling the emotion of fear.  Possibly Harry is afraid of what might happen if he feels fear and turns chicken.  Possibly Harry is surprised at how he manages to stay calm during danger, calm and imagines that it would take a terrible dangerous situation to make him feel fear, and he is afraid of some someday facing a situation so terribly dangerous it makes him feel fear.

Comment: The question was about a _phobia_.  A phobia is a _crippling, paralyzing_ fear, not a garden-variety fear.  Harry isn't prevented from going about his everyday life due to a fear of fear, nor is he prevented from being brave when he needs to be.  He quite obviously doesn't have a phobia.